# Why is input[type="number"] inserting decimal values as ".00"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to insert decimals to my database table, but all I get is trailing "0"s. So for example instead of inserting "0.15" to the database, it inserts as "0.00". And when the typed number is "1.05", it will insert as "1.00". I've added `step="any"` to my input, but see no change. How do I fix my code so it can accept decimal values?

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <input class="i2" name="cshpntamt" type="number" step="any">
    <input class="span2" name="cshamt" type="number" step="any">
    <button type="submit" name="cashptsbut">Cash Out</button>
</form>

function cashPnt(event){
    var a = $(this).parent("form").find('input.i2').val();
    var b = 20;
    var c = a / b;
    var spanNum2 = $(this).parent("form").find('input.span2')[0];
    spanNum2.value = c;
}
$('input.i2').on('change keyup paste input', cashPnt);
```

What my database looks like:

```
cshid     | int(11)
cshpntamt | int(11) 
cshamt    | decimal(10,2)
```

Edit: Updated to include handler.php file:

```
 if(isset($_POST['cashptsbut'])) {
    $cshpntamt = $_POST['cshpntamt'];
    $cshamt = $_POST['cshamt'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cashpoints (cshpntamt, cshamt) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cshpntamt, $cshamt);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Your client javascrtipt code is correct and database field is also ok. you can see your request in browser devtools that expected data is posting to server correctly Please check your server side code in `handler.php` that accepts float or double data type for parameter `cshamt`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23701382)

Comment: Please share your handler.php code for more information

Comment: @Hadi Okay, my request is updated to include my handler.php file

Comment: You are converting the number to integer in the bind_parm statement.  Change the 'ii' to 'dd' or 'ff'.

Comment: @CharlesEF Oh wow, so that's what it was, I did not know that! Wish I could mark you as best answer, thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, Hadi was on the same track.  I guess I looked at the 'handler.php' code before he/she did.  Glad it helped.

Comment: Why have you removed the code snippet? As I question it now makes no sense to any others who might have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CharlesEF gave the solution to this question:

You are converting the number to integer in the bind_parm statement. Change the 'ii' to 'dd' or 'ff'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax: Number((yourNumericValueHere).toFixed(2));

First, you apply .toFixed(2) onto the number that you want to round off the decimal places of. Note that this will convert the value to a string from number.

For Example :
I have an amount that has upto 5 digits in the decimal places and I would like to shorten it to upto 2 decimal places. I do it like so:

```
var price = 0.12345;
var priceRounded = Number((price).toFixed(2));
console.log('Original Price: ' + price);
console.log('Price Rounded: ' + priceRounded);
```

Try this method in your code.hope it will work